# Save data as editable Pdf

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

We have a software, which creates user reports and saves them into pdf documents. We're using Ghostscript for this.

I'm aware that PDF is "normally" an export format which is not editable, but one of our customer needs the possibility (for legal reasons) to edit these files.

I thought it can be possible to save the text in fillable forms (like adobe acrobat offers) and save it that way. Is it possible to create Text within a fillable form in a PDF and save it (with free tools like Ghostscript), so that the user can edit it later?

I read the Ghostscript documentation, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: You cannot do 'forms' which can be filled in using Acrobat Reader without licencing this from Adobe, it relies on Adobe proprietary code. MuPDF can do form filling (of regular AcroForms). If you are using Ghostscript to produce your PDF files then you must be going via PostScript at some point in your process which severely limits what you can do. Note that 'editable' is not the same as form filling or applying annotations, you can put annotations on PDF files produced by Ghostscript. What GS does not have is any GUI to do this.

Comment: Thatis not correct. Many products can create fillable forms.

Comment: @KenS: The licensing is not needed for the editability but for saving the edited PDFs.

Comment: My comment was related to forms which can be filed by Acrobat *Reader*, not AcroForms per se which is a different thing and can be edited by a number of applications (including MuPDF). It is possible to create AcroForms using Ghostscript but you need to write pdfmarks to do it, and this is probably beyond most users knowledge, or desire to learn.

Comment: @KenS You have a link/Example for that? Im just interested, cause i had the same Problem last year... I wanst able to find good reference/examples for pdfmarks (and AcroForms), so i gave up and changed to another format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GhostScript isn't really a terrific tool for this.  You'd be better off with a PDF generation library which can add the appropriate annotations to the page - if you're wedded to using annotations.

If the "content" must be edited by end users, using widget annotations is not a horribly bad way of doing things, except that every end user needs to have a copy of Acrobat and if only some people are allowed to edit, you will likely have to play with owner password protection and permissions in order prevent anyone from changing field contents.

As for free tools, depending on the usage you could use [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) or iTextSharp.

If you are required to be able to take the content of the document and be able to make changes to it on the fly, that's a trickier beast.  If you can afford it (and it's certainly not free), my company Atalasoft, publishes [a product that I wrote](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotpdf/) that lets you build PDF documents from scratch or from templates and embed the .NET objects that create the content into the PDF itself, which means that you can read those objects back out and change the content with a site-specific application, for example.